# ¿Por qué sucede esto con Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Soy nuevo utilizando vue, estoy haciendo un CRUD con laravel y me percaté de algo; cuando envío un json desde el controlador con un nombre no funciona, así se ve:

```
public function index()
{
    $notes = Note::all();
    return response()->json(['notes' => $notes]); 
}
```

[image: no funciona.]

Sin embargo, cuando quito el 'notes' sí funciona, quedando de esta manera:

```
public function index()
{
    $notes = Note::all();
    return response()->json($notes); 
}
```

[image: Funciona]

Código vue:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
        <router-link to="/notes/create" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo</router-link>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Titulo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Contenido</th>
                        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
                        <td>{{ note.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ note.content }}</td>
                        <td>
                <router-link :to="{name:'editNotes', params:{id:note.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</router-link>
                <a type="button" @click="destroyNote(note.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "notes",
    data(){
        return {
            notes:[]
        } 
    },
    mounted(){
        this.showNotes();
    },
    methods:{
        async showNotes() {
            await this.axios.get('/api/notes')
            .then(response => {
                this.notes = response.data;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.notes = [];
            })
        },
        destroyNote(id){
            if (confirm("¿Desea eliminar esta nota?")) {
                this.axios.delete(`/api/notes/${id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.showNotes();
                    })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Me pareció curioso y mi pregunta es a qué se debe este comportamiento y si cambia en algo que lleve o no lleve ese 'notes'. Y de ser posible también conocer la manera de que con 'notes' pueda también mostrar todos los elementos. Gracias.

Comment: Revisa como es el json resultante. En un caso va a ser un array de objetos, y en el otro un objeto con una llave `notes`, y bajo esa llave el array de objetos. Para responder, tendrías que agregar a la pregunta el código de vue

Comment: Hola, gracias por leer y responder. Ya agregué el código de vue, estoy atento a cualquier respuesta. Mil gracias

Comment: La respuesta sigue siendo el primer comentario.. fijate lo que hay dentro de response.data en showNotes